# Is it possible to use socket.io client index.html hosted on Apache to point to nodejs on another port?

Tags: node.js

Is this scenario possible, and if not, how to make it possible?

Assume I have nodejs running on port 8080. I also have Apache running on port 80.
On the nodejs port, I have express with socketIO.

On Apache, I have a index.html webpage with a textbox with a submit button that includes "socket.io-client.js". Entering a message in the textbox and hitting submit would pass the message over to the nodejs on port 80 that would effectively broadcast the message to all other users who have their page open at the index.html hosted on the apache.

From the examples I've seen so far, socketio, the webpage, express, all have to reside with wherever node is, so that the index.html page can include the script "/socketio/socket.io.js". Is there some way I could include the socket.io.js script hosted on a server outside of nodejs? If any example or configuration available that would be needed for this to work would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple include socket.io.js in your index.html by specifying node.js port in srcipt URL like:

```
<script src="http://your.host:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running node.js on same machine as Apache, you could [check out this link](http://arguments.callee.info/2010/04/20/running-apache-and-node-js-together/), it explains how to redirect any connections to node.js for some "folders" within url path.
You will have to run node.js on another port, and then using .htaccess redirect connection to node.js for specific folder within url path.